# Scroll Graph Horizontally in Custom View

Tags: android, graph, horizontalscrollview

I have made a graph by extending View and made graph dynamically
what i want is to scroll that graph
because my mobile screen is smallit takes all xaxis values so i want it to scroll horizontall

What i have done is

```
        HorizontalScrollView hsv=new HorizontalScrollView(this);
            ll=new LinearLayout(this); //taking Linear Layout
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
            ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.addView(graphView);//My Graph 
            hsv.addView(ll);
            setContentView(hsv);
```

I want to this Dynamically because my entire code is dynamic 
 So i need help , it is not showing the graph when i implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do one thing, instead of trying scroll graph

Horizontally try to swipe drawing lines and points ,its easy

all we have to swipe canvas view

Comment: how can i do that ? gimme any example

Comment: well i dnt know what kind of example(or API) ur using for displaying graph , try AchartEngine(http://www.achartengine.org/) this is very good example it contains all kinds of graph

Comment: well i know how to make a chart all i want is,how to scroll the view horizontally Dats all i want

Comment: in that example they have given best example how to scroll horizontally....check it once....if still ur unable to fine i will give u exmple

Comment: Well Thanks fr your concern 
I have Gone throu it
What i have done after reading is i have made an xml and given id to LinearLayout after getting the ID of LinearLayout in java filee and give parameters but still it is not showing

Comment: Well Working on Chart android let  see what happens yet to supply this

Comment: I have successfully insttlled Achart its working fine but what if i want to Scroll the Same view whos code is given above

Comment: i have used same code to scroll it worked well for me , try it very good code and easy....any doubts about scrolling i will provide code of mine..

Comment: If You are talking about AchartEngine then it is also working for me 
But i mtalking Case Without AchartEngine
basically my problem is up here see my link but the same code oMy LINK is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478060/how-to-scroll-canvas-to-improve-x-axis